# Postgres update substitutes 11 for -1

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

This is a very strange one, I'm attempting to update a row in a postgres table. I can update it to any value I like except -1 (minus one).

This is the update statement I'm using....

```
UPDATE flight 
SET turns = -1
WHERE (firstTime >= '24-Feb-2018 00:00:00' 
AND lastTime <= '24-Feb-2018 23:59:00') 
AND device = '3ECC38'
```

And this is the SELECT statement I'm using to check the results....

```
SELECT *
FROM flight 
WHERE  (firstTime >= '24-Feb-2018 00:00:00' AND lastTime <= '24-Feb-
2018 23:59:00' )
AND device = '3ECC38'
```

I can edit the UPDATE query to set 'turns' to any number I like (positive or negative) the SELECT statement indicates that the UPDATE works correctly. The only exception is when I set 'turns = -1', I run the select statement and it shows turns has been set to 11 (eleven).
The error is consistent on this table, but I'm unable to replicate in on any similar table.
There is some curious behavior associated with this error, for instance I can set 'turns' to -2, if I try to increment it by one (SET turns = turns+1) then it's value becomes 11, not -1.

There appears to be one way of setting 'turns' to minus 1. I start by setting it some other acceptable value ("SET turns = 2") then I can set it to -1 by with "SET turns = '-1'::INTEGER"

- Version is “PostgreSQL 9.5.7 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by
  gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit”
- I'm running the queries using pgAdmin3 (version 1.23.0b)
- The UPDATE never returns an error, it simply says "Query returned successfully: one row affected"
- There is only one row that matches the selection criterea.

The table was created using this....

```
CREATE TABLE public.flight
(
  flightid SERIAL,
  firstime timestamp without time zone,
  lasttime timestamp without time zone,
  deviceid character(6),
  fixcount integer,
  turns integer DEFAULT '-1'::integer
)

CREATE INDEX flight_idx_001
  ON public.flight
  USING btree
  (deviceid COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

There are no triggers on the table.

The DDL I actually ran to create the table set the default as this....

```
turns           INTEGER DEFAULT -1
```

pgAdmin3 has changed it to that listed above

I have run the query from a C# application and from PSQL console - the results are the same.

I have noticed another 'feature' that may be relevant. If I define a field as an integer and specify a positive default value then that get accepted without trouble, however if I specify a negative integer value then the default gets modified to a string cast to an integer.

Comment: Is there any trigger on this table?

Comment: Why `DEFAULT '-1'::integer` instead of `DEFAULT (-1)`?

Comment: Check the statement using psql, not pgAdmin3.